# WSO2 Identity Server SAML 2.0 (Error when decoding the SAML Request)

Tags: c#, wso2, saml, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am creating SAML 2.0 request as given below

```
string samlRequestXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><samlp:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL=\"https://localhost:44395/home/AssertionPage\" Destination=\"https://localhost:9443/samlsso\" ForceAuthn=\"false\" ID=\"hloijnnfkolebkokdhgicdfehjdkkoblhekbcapg\" IsPassive=\"false\" IssueInstant=\"2023-07-20T13:20:31.134Z\" ProtocolBinding=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST\" Version=\"2.0\" xmlns:samlp=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol\"><samlp:Issuer xmlns:samlp=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion\">MAssertionName</samlp:Issuer><saml2p:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate=\"true\" Format=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent\" SPNameQualifier=\"Issuer\" xmlns:saml2p=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol\"/><saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison=\"exact\" xmlns:saml2p=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol\"><saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion\">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef></saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext></samlp:AuthnRequest>";

                
byte[] samlRequestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(samlRequestXml);
string encodedSamlRequest = Convert.ToBase64String(samlRequestBytes);
string URL_Encode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encodedSamlRequest);
string request = "https://localhost:9443/samlsso?SAMLRequest=" + URL_Encode;
return Redirect(request);
```

Please Tell me what I am doing Wrong. I am getting below error in console

```
Error when processing the authentication request! org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Error when decoding the SAML Request.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SAML request XML string, you are using double quotation marks for attributes inside the XML tags. However, the outer string is enclosed in double quotation marks as well. This can cause conflicts in the string structure. You should use single quotation marks for the outer string and double quotation marks for attribute values inside the XML tags.

Update lines like this:

```
"<samlp:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://localhost:44395/home/AssertionPage" ...
```

to:

```
"<samlp:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL='https://localhost:44395/home/AssertionPage' ...
```

It seems like you are URL encoding the entire SAML request, including the base64-encoded XML. You should only URL encode the base64-encoded XML string.

Modify this line

```
string request = "https://localhost:9443/samlsso?SAMLRequest=" + URL_Encode;
```

to

```
string request = "https://localhost:9443/samlsso?SAMLRequest=" + encodedSamlRequest;
```

After that your code need to be look like below.

```
string samlRequestXml = "<samlp:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL='https://localhost:44395/home/AssertionPage' Destination='https://localhost:9443/samlsso' ForceAuthn='false' ID='hloijnnfkolebkokdhgicdfehjdkkoblhekbcapg' IsPassive='false' IssueInstant='2023-07-20T13:20:31.134Z' ProtocolBinding='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST' Version='2.0' xmlns:samlp='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'><samlp:Issuer xmlns:samlp='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion'>MAssertionName</samlp:Issuer><saml2p:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate='true' Format='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent' SPNameQualifier='Issuer' xmlns:saml2p='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'/><saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison='exact' xmlns:saml2p='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'><saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion'>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef></saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext></samlp:AuthnRequest>";

byte[] samlRequestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(samlRequestXml);
string encodedSamlRequest = Convert.ToBase64String(samlRequestBytes);
string URL_Encode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encodedSamlRequest);

string request = "https://localhost:9443/samlsso?SAMLRequest=" + encodedSamlRequest;

return Redirect(request);
```